# SSH. Too many logins for Username. Why if i have logged only 2nd time and have tmux ssh in other servers tmux?

Tags: server, ssh, login, tmux, ps

Logging just once in shh, after i lost wifi connection, that has 10 login limit i got

```
Too many logins for 'username'.
Last login: Thu May  6 17:06:43 2021 from 62.85.107.197
Connection to servername.xyz closed.
```

I asked server admin to help he sent screenshot with command `ps xua|grep username`.

[image]

How does it works then? I have logged only one time. Previous wifi connection lost maybe got one connection hung up in air, but how long until it disappears?

When im only in ssh without tmux restored i have

[image]

When i open tmux and log in other servers, then i get

[image]

What makes count of logged in connections? Does each tmux window and each pane counts as a log i or session? What to do when i cant get in? Some another remote log in to terminate connections? Some way to make session chron check some website file when i need to reset then to do `tmux kill-server` if file on some website is 0.

Comment: "Does each tmux window and each pane counts as a log i or session? " Yes. "What to do when i cant get in?"  have the admin kill a few and do not exceed 9 so you have at least 1 remaining to kill them yourself. Or have the admin create a script to kill the oldest when #9 starts. **You really need to ask the admin as he knows what is possible** "What makes count of logged in connections?" **this one too... ask the admin what he uses to count and see if he can change it :)**

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Answer (score 1):

Someone will likely know more than me for this, but I know it's the case that
every tmux split pane adds one more instance of `USER` to the list of logged in
users. So if you had 9 tmux panes (perhaps distributed through a number of
sessions and windows) that will show as you being logged on 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already gotten yourself into this situation, then you need to ask an admin to help you kill the `tmux` session. However, it's possible to prevent this in the future by changing `tmux`'s behaviour.

If you add `set -g default-command "${SHELL}"` to `~/.tmux.conf`, then `tmux` won't increase the count for logged in users for your account [0].

[0] https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/tmux#Start_a_non-login_shell